# Not able to install checkstyle or PMD

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle, pmd

I'm getting the following error while installing checkstyle in ecclipse.

Unable to read repository at https://dl.bintray.com/eclipse-cs/eclipse-cs/8.0.0/content.xml.

exception stack trace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:421)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:150)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:575)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I'm getting same error for PMD also.

Comment: The `https://dl.bintray.com/eclipse-cs/eclipse-cs/8.0.0/` looks okay to me. How did you install it (via Marketplace or directly via the update site) and when do you get this error? Which version of Eclipse and of Java do you use?

Comment: I tried both ways
I am using eclipse kepler and mars with java 7.

Comment: I even downloaded it and tried adding using archive option in 'Install new software'. But it is not working

Comment: Use Java 8 instead of Java 7 (Java 7 supports shorter keys than Java 8).

Comment: I can't use java 8. My project is on java 7.

Comment: Does running Eclipse on Java 8 fix your problem?